# Mini ToC page numbering styling

Tags: page-numbering

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{shapes.misc}

\titlecontents{psection}[2.3em]
{\large}{\contentslabel{2.3em}}{}{\tikz \node[draw,inner sep=2pt,rounded corners,fill=red!30]{@\contentspage};}

%draw,inner sep=2pt,rounded corners,fill=red!30
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chp 1}
% list of sections
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{p}{1}{}

\section{Sec 1}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Sec 2}
\lipsum[1-3]

\section{Sec 3}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chp 2}
% list of sections
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{p}{1}{}

\section{Sec 1}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Sec 2}
\lipsum[1-3]

\section{Sec 3}
\lipsum[1]
 
\end{document}
```

I want the page numbers to be styled with a color-filled rectangle shown in the figure. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should to use `\thecontentspage` that only contains the page number in an unformatted way which can be used inside a Ti*k*z node:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\titlecontents{psection}[2.3em]
{\large}{\contentslabel{2.3em}}{}{\hspace*{.5em}\tikz[baseline]{\node[draw, inner sep=2pt, rounded corners, fill=red!30, anchor=base]{\thecontentspage};}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chp 1}
% list of sections
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{p}{1}{}

\section{Sec 1}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Sec 2}
\lipsum[1-3]

\section{Sec 3}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chp 2}
% list of sections
\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{p}{1}{}

\section{Sec 1}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Sec 2}
\lipsum[1-3]

\section{Sec 3}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great in deed!